# Single SQL Query with inner joins

Tags: sql

Ok so basically I have 2 tables, one is with users and the other with follow logs, I have a PHP script in which I need to send a request to find a user to follow.

Alright, let's say I'm on the user 'gretar' (promote_account) and I need to find a user to follow, I need to select all users that have promotion_left > 0 and isn't in followed_account WHERE twitter_name is 'gretar'.

users_table:
[image]

follow_table:
[image]

**EDIT: Read everything over and I clearly didn't explain it well enough, sorry about that, I've changed it now.**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It's basically, how can I make a single SELECT query that does all of the things listed above.

Answer (score 0):

You want a left outer join to show the users who do not have a record in the follow table.  So in TSQL, it would look like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM users_table u
  LEFT OUTER JOIN follow_table f ON f.followed_account = u.promote_account
    AND twitter_name = 'gretar'
  WHERE f.id IS NULL
    AND u.promotion_left > 0
    AND u.promote_account <> 'gretar'
```

Comment: Oh, a PHP app?  Does that mean you're using MySQL?

Comment: It goes through PHP and returns in json but the main thing is the SQL query.

Comment: But the database is a MySQL database?  The type of database determines the syntax.

Comment: Yes it is a MySQL database.

Comment: I've edited my previous answer to use MySQL 5.6.  Here is the SQLFiddle link:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d118/2